# KMeans Clustering - Getting "malloc" error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, malloc, k-means

I'm trying to run kmeans clustering on a dataset with ~120,000 datapoints but I am getting a 'malloc' error:

```
python3(2830,0x70000d545000) malloc: *** error for object 0xc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(2830,0x70000e54b000) malloc: *** error for object 0xc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(2830,0x70000dd48000) malloc: *** error for object 0xc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(2830,0x70000ed4e000) malloc: *** error for object 0xc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(2830,0x70000d545000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
python3(2830,0x70000dd48000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
python3(2830,0x70000e54b000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
python3(2830,0x70000ed4e000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
python3(2830,0x70000f551000) malloc: *** error for object 0xc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(2830,0x70000f551000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    2830 abort      python3 kmeans.py
```

The data is in an ndarray formatters as such:

```
[[2.06e+01 1.03e+00]
 [2.06e+01 1.70e-01]
 [2.06e+01 1.03e+00]
 ...
 [2.42e+01 2.30e-01]
 [2.36e+01 1.00e-02]
 [2.41e+01 1.40e-01]]
```

I've ran various supervised models on the same dataset without any issue. My code here:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

df = pd.read_csv('data/final_dataset.csv')

df = df[df['Episode_Count'].notna()]

#create X coords 
X = df[['BMI','Episode_Count']].values

plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])
plt.show() 

#train model 
k = 5
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=42)
y_pred = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
print(y_pred)
```

I know this is not reproducible but that is difficult with such a large dataset. I'm happy to find a way to share training data if that would help.

Has anybody ran into this issue before??

Comment: appears to be a memory issue! you can try to bump up `n_clusters` and lower the `max_iter`. Another option would be training through batches - [MiniBatchKMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html)

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, it was also killing the cluster when I tried running in a jupyter notebook. Thanks!

Comment: if you can share the dataset `final_dataset.csv` somehow! I can try to run it on my machine

Comment: Please find here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cre290oX0u43Hu1a3ZGU7NGTtNz-3LLE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it ran fine for me, I am on mac with 24GB, refer to [notebook](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/jupyter_notebooks/blob/main/kMeans_so_post.ipynb), fyip.. tried in batch with file name `kmeans.py` and worked okay too.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind creating an example with the batch approach? I tried following the documentation but got the error: ```ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 2)) while a minimum of 1 is required.```. I am still quite new to all of this.